# Правильная организация кода JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

как во Vue.js правильно реализовать данный код ?

```
if ($delivery_id == 3375 or 1504) {$delivery = "Почта России";}
if ($delivery_id == 1495) {$delivery = "Boxberry";}
if ($delivery_id == 1516) {$delivery = "CDEK";}
if ($delivery_id == 1382) {$delivery = "Pick Point";}
if ($delivery_id == 1492) {$delivery = "СТРИЖ";}
if ($delivery_id == 1385) {$delivery = "ПЭК";}
if ($delivery_id == 1501) {$delivery = "DPD";}
if ($delivery_id == 1510) {$delivery = "Maxi Post";}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const $postMap = {
    3375: 'Почта России',
    1504: 'Почта России',
    1495: 'Boxberry',
};

const $delivery = $postMap[$delivery_id] || 'Неизвестная компания';
```

Можно организовать функцию:

```
function getDeliveryResolver() {
    // Однократно формируем словарь в замыкании
    const RUSSIA_POST = {title: 'Почта России'};
    const $postMap = {
        3375: RUSSIA_POST,
        1504: RUSSIA_POST,
        1495: {title: 'Boxberry'},
    };
    // Возвращаем функцию-резольвер
    return id => $postMap[id] || {title: 'Неизвестная компания'};
}    
const deliveryResolver = getDeliveryResolver();
const delivery = deliveryResolver(delivery_id);
const deliveryTitle = delivery.title;
```

Можно пойти дальше и организовать класс =)

```js
class Delivery {
  POST_UNKNOWN  = {title: 'Неизвестная компания'};
  POST_RUSSIAN  = {title: 'Почта России'};
  POST_BOXBERRY = {title: 'Boxberry'};

  map = {
    3375: this.POST_RUSSIAN,
    1504: this.POST_RUSSIAN,
    1495: this.POST_BOXBERRY,
  };

  resolve(id) {
    return this.map[id] || this.POST_UNKNOWN;
  }
}

const delivery = new Delivery();

console.log(delivery.resolve(1504).title);
console.log(delivery.resolve(1495).title);
console.log(delivery.resolve(1504) === delivery.POST_RUSSIAN);
console.log(delivery.resolve(1000).title);
```

Answer (score 2):

Сделать маппинг, например:

```js
const getDeliveryService = (deliveryId) => {
  const SERVICES = {
    3375: 'Почта России',
    1495: 'Boxberry',
    // Остальные нужные сервисы
  };

  return SERVICES[deliveryId] || 'нет доступных сервисов доставки';
};

console.log(getDeliveryService(3375));
```